# "Bigint" decimal to two's complement binary list of bytes in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, number-systems

I'm toying with the idea of writing a "bigint" library in 6502
assembler that would handle variable-length integers up to 255 bytes
long. Since this would be unit tested using pytest, and to help wrap
my mind around the representation issues, I've come up with a function
in Python that takes a decmial integer and deposits it into (emulated)
memory as its binary representation: as a length byte followed by the
bytes of the value from least to most significant. (The 6502 is
little-endian.) This could be used, for example, to generate a couple
of inputs to test an "add" or "multiply" function.

As background, the `M` or `Machine` object here is the emulated CPU
and RAM, with the RAM as an array of unsigned 0-255 integers. It
offers a `deposit(addr, list)` method to put values into memory,
`byte(addr)` to retrive a single byte, and `bytes(addr, len)` to
retrieve multiple bytes. (This is actually a wrapper around a
`py65.devices.mpu6502` from [py65](https://github.com/mnaberez/py65); all the code is in my [8bitdev](https://github.com/0cjs/8bitdev)
repo if you're curious.)

```py
from    testmc.m6502 import  Machine, Registers as R, Instructions as I
import  pytest

@pytest.fixture
def M():
    M = Machine()
    M.load('.build/obj/objects')
    return M

def depint(M, addr, value):
    ''' Deposit a bigint in locations starting at `addr`.
        `addr` contains the length of the following bytes,
        which hold the value from LSB to MSB.
    '''

    next = addr + 1             # Skip length byte; filled in at end

    if value >= 0:              # Positive number; fill byte by byte
        while next == addr+1 or value > 0:
            value, byte = divmod(value, 0x100)
            M.deposit(next, [byte])
            next += 1
        if byte >= 0x80:        # MSbit = 1; sign in additional byte
            M.deposit(next, [0x00])
            next += 1

    else:                       # Negative: fill with two's complement values
        value = abs(value+1)    # two's complement = -(n+1)
        while next == addr+1 or value > 0:
            value, byte = divmod(value, 0x100)
            byte = 0xFF - byte  # two's complement
            M.deposit(next, [byte])
            next += 1
        if byte < 0x80:         # MSbit = 0; sign in additional byte
            M.deposit(next, [0xFF])
            next += 1

    #   Store the length
    M.deposit(addr, [next - (addr + 1)])

@pytest.mark.parametrize('value, bytes', [
    (0,             [0x00]),
    (1,             [0x01]),
    (127,           [0x7F]),
    (128,           [0x80, 0x00]),
    (255,           [0xFF, 0x00]),
    (256,           [0x00, 0x01]),
    (0x40123456,    [0x56, 0x34, 0x12, 0x40]),
    (0xC0123456,    [0x56, 0x34, 0x12, 0xC0, 0x00]),
    (-1,            [0xFF]),
    (-128,          [0x80]),
    (-129,          [0x7F, 0xFF]),
    (-255,          [0x01, 0xFF]),
    (-256,          [0x00, 0xFF]),
    (-257,          [0xFF, 0xFE]),
    (0-0x40123456,  [0xFF-0x56+1, 0xFF-0x34, 0xFF-0x12, 0xFF-0x40]),
    (0-0xC0123456,  [0xFF-0x56+1, 0xFF-0x34, 0xFF-0x12, 0xFF-0xC0, 0xFF]),
    ])
def test_depint(M, value, bytes):
    print('DEPOSIT', value, 'expecting', bytes)
    addr = 30000                    # arbitrary location for deposit
    size = len(bytes) + 2           # length byte + value + guard byte
    M.deposit(addr, [222] * size)   # 222 ensures any 0s really were written
    depint(M, addr, value)
    bvalue = M.bytes(addr+1, len(bytes))
    assert (len(bytes),   bytes,  222) \
        == (M.byte(addr), bvalue, M.byte(addr+size-1))

    #   Test against Python's conversion
    assert list(value.to_bytes(len(bytes), 'little', signed=True)) \
        == bvalue
```

Things you might consider when reviewing:

- Is it actually correct? Do the tests provide sufficient coverage?
  (FWIW, in this particular implementation I don't feel the need to
  test for overflow, since all input values would be fully under my
  control.)
- Is there a clearer way to describe the tests?
- The `next == addr+1` condition in the `while` loops is a bit
  awkward; is there a better way of handling this? The obvious thing
  would be to use a `do` loop (the first time I can recall wanting one
  in a *long* time), but Python doesn't have them.
- Perhaps it would make more sense just to use Python's `bit_length()`
  and `to_bytes()` to handle the conversion.
- Regarding how useful this is, it's occurred to me that I'll probably
  want a reader routine (in 6502 assembler) to do this same ASCII
  decmal → bigint conversion, which would mean I could just unit test
  it using Python's `to_bytes()` and use that routine in unit tests
  for add, multiply, etc. routines. The only issue might be that it
  could be a lot slower in 6502 emulation than using the native Python
  library would be.

Answer (score 1):

### Name shadowing

```
next = addr + 1             # Skip length byte; filled in at end
```

Don't call a variable `next`. That's already a built-in. You could use `next_addr` for example.

Similarly,

```
def test_depint(M, value, bytes):
```

should not use the built-in name `bytes`. I'm not completely clear on what it does in context, but maybe `message`, `deposit`, `deposit_span`, etc. are possible.

### Masking

```
        value, byte = divmod(value, 0x100)
```

Are you sure that this shouldn't just be

```
byte = value & 0xFF
value >>= 8
```

### Assert decomposition

> Is there a clearer way to describe the tests?

```
assert (len(bytes),   bytes,  222) \
    == (M.byte(addr), bvalue, M.byte(addr+size-1))
```

Don't combine this. Tests are more useful if you can see exactly which term in an assertion failed:

```
assert len(bytes) == M.byte(addr)
assert bytes == bvalue
assert M.byte(addr+size-1) == 222
```

### f-strings

```
print('DEPOSIT', value, 'expecting', bytes)
```

can be

```
print(f'DEPOSIT {value} expecting {bytes}')
```

Comment: Can you suggest better names for the ones you don't like?

Comment: Sure thing; edited

Comment: Regarding `value &= ~0xFF`; that does something different from the `divmod()`: the latter returns the _quotient_ and remainder, not the original value minus the remainder. If I merely subtracted the remainder from `value`, on the next round there would be no further remainder (it's already been subtracted) and `value` would stay the same forever, causing an infinite loop. (I think; it's late here and I'm a bit tired.)

Comment: My mistake. That should have been a bitshift.

Comment: `bytes` is the list of bytes that were deposited in memory. I'm not entirely clear with the issues on using my own variable names that shadow built-ins; variable names (though perhaps not so frequently built-ins) are shadowed all the time even in the Python core source, both as [local vars](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/pdb.py#L403-L404) and  in public interfaces ([nntplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/nntplib.html?highlight=next#nntplib.NNTP.next), [tarfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html?highlight=next#tarfile.TarFile.next)). What does `next` shadow?

Comment: Combining the tests is very useful. If one of the values fails, you can look at the others to see more context. In your variant, the error message is "40 bytes expected, got only 36, but I don't tell you anything about their values", which is it not helpful.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next

Comment: Re "don't combine": I combined the three so I can see all of values if any one or more of them fails; I found this to make debugging significantly easier. It does show you exactly which term failed (and which ones didn't); the position in the tuple shows it. (With enough `-v` options, pytest prints out two lines and points out the differences within them.) I believe Roland is [pointing out the same thing](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/230693/bigint-decimal-to-twos-complement-binary-list-of-bytes-in-python/230717#comment449684_230717).

Comment: It's an awkward way of getting context. If you're _actually_ debugging, your debugger can break at the point where the assertion failure is raised, and you'll have all of the context you need. Otherwise, to see the parameter values, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57136918/pytest-show-parameter-values-in-failure-report

Comment: Ah, re the mask and bitshift: yes, I think that's more clear.

Comment: Re the f-strings: I like them better, but I still am using Python 3.5 on some systems which I think does not have them, does it?

Comment: That's unfortunately true :/ https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498